# What does 'T' and 'U' stand for in the Vscode debugger?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

As you can see in the images below, when you hover over a variable during a debugging session, a little hover box appears which shows you the value of that variable. Very handy indeed, but what does `'T'` and `'U'` mean?

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters?

Comment: Yeah this would make sense - just not obvious. Why not show the hex value as well? ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

As @GSerg suggested, it represents the [ASCII "character" representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) of that value.